# Removing Duplicate from map

Tags: apex, sales

I have created a map of type

```
Map<Id, Set<Id>> missingProduct= new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
Set<Id> prd = new Set<Id>();
```

However on running the loop and storing the values duplicate map values are been stored without removing the value of the previous map.

```
for(Product_Objective__c  prdObj :allObjectives ){ 
      prdobject = new Product_Objective__c  ();

      prd.add(prdobject.Product__c);


      missingProduct.put(prdobject.Account__c,prd);

      system.debug('missingProduct'+missingProduct);
}
```

Map is having the values of the previous set also stored with all value. I am unable to make it null for new key.

```
 Set<Id> prd = new Set<Id>();
```

Comment: what's your requirement ? what are you trying to achieve ? in the for loop you are creating a new instance of Product Objective and using its fields (which will all be null to start with)

Comment: Inside the loop check for the key, does map contains the key or not using `Map.containsKey(key)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am guessing that `Product_Objective__c`  is a child of Account and you want a map of `AccountIds` to a set of `Product_Objective__c` Ids.

You need to check if the map contains the account id or not, if yes fetch the existing set from the map and then add the new item or create a new set and put in the map.

Problems with your existing code.

```
for(Product_Objective__c  prdObj :allObjectives ){ 
      prdobject = new Product_Objective__c  (); //new instance

      prd.add(prdobject.Product__c); //so, Product__c will be null anyway.


      missingProduct.put(prdobject.Account__c,prd); //putting the one id Set against the account id.
//you are not nullifying the set here to reuse it next time.
      system.debug('missingProduct'+missingProduct);
}
```

Rather, make it cleaner.

```
for(Product_Objective__c  prdObj :allObjectives ){ 

    if(missingProduct.containsKey(prdObj.Account__c))
    {
        missingProduct.get(prdObj.Account__c).add(prdObj.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        missingProduct.put(prdObj.Account__c, new Set<Id>{prdObj.Id});
    }
}
System.debug('missingProduct'+missingProduct);
```

This should give you a map of Account Ids to a set of Product_Objective__c Ids.

Comment: I tend to prefer adding the empty set for missing keys and then unconditionally adding elements, but it basically amounts to the same thing.